# How to mount container-writable host directory?

Tags: macos, docker, file-permissions, docker-compose, docker-toolbox

I'm attempting to run an ELK stack using Docker. I found [docker-elk](https://github.com/deviantony/docker-elk) which has already set up the config for me, using `docker-compose`.

I'd like to store the elasticsearch data on the host machine instead of a container. As per docker-elk's README, I added a `volumes` line to `elasticsearch`'s section of `docker-compose.yml`:

```
elasticsearch:
  image: elasticsearch:latest
  command: elasticsearch -Des.network.host=0.0.0.0
  ports:
    - "9200"
    - "9300"
  volumes:
    - ../../env/elasticsearch:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
```

However, when I run `docker-compose up` I get:

```
$ docker-compose up
Starting dev_elasticsearch_1
Starting dev_logstash_1
Starting dev_kibana_1
Attaching to dev_elasticsearch_1, dev_logstash_1, dev_kibana_1
kibana_1        | Stalling for Elasticsearch
elasticsearch_1 | [2016-03-09 00:23:35,193][WARN ][bootstrap                ] unable to install syscall filter: seccomp unavailable: your kernel is buggy and you should upgrade
elasticsearch_1 | Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to access 'path.data' (/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/elasticsearch)
elasticsearch_1 | Likely root cause: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data/elasticsearch
elasticsearch_1 |   at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:84)
elasticsearch_1 |   at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
elasticsearch_1 |   at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
... etc ...
```

Looking in `../../env`, the `elasticsearch` directory was indeed created, but it was empty. If I create `../../env/elasticsearch/elasticsearch` then I get an access error for `/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/elasticsearch/nodes`. If I creates `/nodes` then I get an error for `/nodes/0`, etc...

In short, it appears that the container doesn't have write permissions on the directory.

How do I get it to have write permissions? I tried `chmod a+wx ../../env/elasticsearch`, and then it manages to create the next directory, but that directory has permission `drwxr-xr-x` and it gets stuck again.

I don't like the idea of having to run this as root.

Comment: What is the output of `docker-compose run --rm elasticsearch stat -c "%U %G" /usr/share/elasticsearch/data`?

Comment: @kojiro: I get `UNKNOWN staff`

Answer (score 2):

Docker doesn't tend to worry about these things in its base images because it expects you to use volumes or volume containers. Mounting to the host gets second class support. But as long as the UID that owns the directory is not zero (and it seems it's not based on our comment exchange) you should be able to get away with running elasticsearch as the user who already owns the directory. You could try removing and re-adding the elasticsearch user from the container, specifying its UID.

You would need to do this at entrypoint time, so your best bet would be to build a custom container. Create a file called `my-entrypoint` with these contents:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Allow running arbitrary one-off commands
[[ $1 && $1 != elasticsearch ]] && exec "$@"
# Otherwise, fix perms and then delegate the rest to vanilla
target_uid=$(stat -c %u /usr/share/elasticsearch/data)
userdel elasticsearch
useradd -u "$target_uid" elasticsearch
. /docker-entrypoint "$@"
```

Make sure it's executable. Then create a Dockerfile with these contents:

```
FROM elasticsearch
COPY my-entrypoint /
ENTRYPOINT ["/my-entrypoint"]
```

And finally update your docker-compose.yml file:

```
elasticsearch:
  build: .
  command: elasticsearch -Des.network.host=0.0.0.0
  ports:
    - "9200"
    - "9300"
  volumes:
    - ../../env/elasticsearch:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
```

Now when you run `docker-compose up` it should build an elasticsearch container with your changes.

(I had to do something like this once [with apache for Magento](https://github.com/kojiromike/docker-magento/blob/master/apache/start_safe_perms).)

Comment: Ahh interesting! I tried what you wrote here but it didn't end up working... first I figured it was `/docker-entrypoint.sh`, not `/docker-entrypoint`, but then it still didn't work. I decided, though, based on your first two sentences, to make my life easier and just use named volumes instead.